# Twitter API upgrade for Windows Phone

Tags: api, windows-phone-7, twitter

I have tweet poster in my application which uses **oAuth 1.0** which will retire soon and will be non functional. I have to upgrade my API to **1.1**. Twitter development center says that, If oAuth is used by your application, you can easily transaction to **1.1** by only updating your **API endpoint.** *What exactly is API endpoint?*

Here I'm having hard understanding about API endpoint. I think my asyncronous post call URL must be upgraded.

**Here is the relevant codes which I think that might include the answer;**

```
private void btnPostTweet_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        namebocx.Text = userScreenName;
        if (txtBoxNewTweet.Text.Trim().Length == 0) { return; }

        var credentials = new OAuthCredentials
        {
            Type = OAuthType.ProtectedResource,
            SignatureMethod = OAuthSignatureMethod.HmacSha1,
            ParameterHandling = OAuthParameterHandling.HttpAuthorizationHeader,
            ConsumerKey = TwitterSettings.consumerKey,
            ConsumerSecret = TwitterSettings.consumerKeySecret,
            Token = this.accessToken,
            TokenSecret = this.accessTokenSecret,
            Version = "1.0"
        };

        var restClient = new RestClient
        {
            Authority = TwitterSettings.StatusUpdateUrl,
            HasElevatedPermissions = true,
            Credentials = credentials,
            Method = WebMethod.Post
        };

        restClient.AddHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");

        // Create a Rest Request and fire it
        var restRequest = new RestRequest
        {
            Path = "1/statuses/update.xml?status=" + txtBoxNewTweet.Text //Here must be endpoint of Api??
        };

        var ByteData = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(txtBoxNewTweet.Text);
        restRequest.AddPostContent(ByteData);
        restClient.BeginRequest(restRequest, new RestCallback(PostTweetRequestCallback));
    }
}
```

**and also here is the authentication settings:**

```
public class TwitterSettings
{
    public static string RequestTokenUri = "https://api.twitter.com/oauth/request_token";
    public static string AuthorizeUri = "https://api.twitter.com/oauth/authorize";
    public static string AccessTokenUri = "https://api.twitter.com/oauth/access_token";

    public static string CallbackUri = "http://www.google.com";

    public static string StatusUpdateUrl { get { return "http://api.twitter.com"; } }


    public static string consumerKey = "myconsumerkeyhere";
    public static string consumerKeySecret = "myconsumersecrethere";

    public static string oAuthVersion = "1.0a";
}
```

Here what twitter says me to replace with this instead of written in my code;
**https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/update.json**
and some parameters told here -->> https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1.1/post/statuses/update

How should I update my API endpoint, what kind of changes do I have to do?

If you can help me, I really appreciate

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can change this:

```
Path = "1/statuses/update.xml?status=" + txtBoxNewTweet.Text 
//Here must be endpoint of Api??
```

to this:

```
Path = "1.1/statuses/update.json?status=" + txtBoxNewTweet.Text 
//Here must be endpoint of Api??
```